# Drawing bitmaps via BitmapBrush onto SlimDX Geometry (VB.NET )

Tags: vb.net, bitmapimage, direct2d, slimdx

I have a program where I am attempting to render an image in Direct2D onto a quadrilateral using SlimDX and VB.net.

The program gets an array of 4 points from a server, which are a quadrilateral, where the image should be rendered onto.

The points (For example) are:

```
points(0) = 20,10 <--Top left, where the geometry starts from
points(1) = 40,10 <-- Top right
points(2) = 40,40 <-- Bottom right
points(3) = 20,40 <-- Bottom left
```

...A BitmapBrush is constructed when loading and the Bitmap can be rendered fine, but when trying to render onto the quadrilateral, I only get (it seems...) some part the bottom right corner.

For reference: Here is the image I'm trying to draw:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/edLQA.png

And here is the code that I'm trying to use (for drawing the image).
R is the point list (see above) and RenderBrush is a BitmapBrush created from a 20x30 version of that image.

```
Private Sub DrawPoly(R() As PointF, ByRef RenderBrush As SlimDX.Direct2D.BitmapBrush)
    'Create the geometry
    Dim Path As PathGeometry
    Path = New PathGeometry(factoryD2D)
    Console.Clear()
    'Get a handle to the Geometry
    Dim Geometry = Path.Open()
    'Set UP Geometry
    Geometry.BeginFigure(R(0), FigureBegin.Filled)
    Geometry.AddLines(R)
    Geometry.EndFigure(FigureEnd.Closed)
    Geometry.Close()

    'Render
    D2DRenderTarget.FillGeometry(Path, RenderBrush)
    'and GC
    Geometry.Dispose()
    Path.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm still not sure, the brush just doesn't seem to be drawing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. To get it to draw onto the geometry, you need to set up a transformation matrix like so:

```
Matrix3x2.Multiply(Matrix3x2.Translation(Point_To_Move_To), Matrix3x2.Rotation(Rotation, Point_To_Rotate_Around))
```